# Solve $f'^2(x)(x^2 + f^2(x)) = s x (x f'^2(x) -x - 2 f(x) f'(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $s>1$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow [0,\infty[$ differentiable be given.
How to solve
$$f'^2(x)(x^2  + f^2(x)) = s x (x f'^2(x) -x - 2 f(x) f'(x))\tag{1}$$
for $x$?

Is it even possible to find an explicit formula for $x$?
Using inverse function wasn't working for me.

This might be a particular example of the general problem
$$F(x,f(x),f'(x))=s.$$

*Note that this is not a differential equation since $f$ is given.*

Property: Let $s y$ solve (1) for $f$ then
$$f'^2(s y)(s^2 y^2  + f^2(s y)) = s^2 y (s y f'^2(s y) -s y - 2 f(s y) f'(s y)).$$
Using $h(y)=s^{-1}f(s y)$ gives
$$h'^2(y)(y^2  + h^2(y)) = s y (y h'^2(y) - y - 2 h(y) h'( y)).$$
So $y$ solves (1) for $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant but it worked:

1. Put $f(x)=x h(x)$ then
   $$(x h'(x)+h(x))^2 (1  + h^2(x)) = s \left( x^2 h'^2(x)- h^2(x)-1\right).$$
2. Now, set $x=\exp(y)$ and $g = h\circ \exp$ then
   $$\left(g'(y)+g(y)\right)^2 \left(1  + g^2(y)\right) = s \left( g'^2(y)- g^2(y)-1\right).$$
3. If $g$ is invertible we can obtain for $y=g^{-1}(z)$ and $\phi=\frac{1}{(g^{-1})'}$
   $$\left(\phi(z) +z\right)^2 \left(1  + z^2\right) = s \left( \phi^2(z)- z^2-1\right).$$
4. Progressing with $\phi(z)=\frac{\sigma(z) \sqrt{1+z^2}-z(1+z^2)}{1+z^2-s} $ leads to
   $$\sigma(z)^2= s^2-s,$$
   with solution $z=\sigma^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{s^2-s}\right)$.

The solution to (1) is then
$$x= h^{-1} \left(\sigma^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{s^2-s}\right)\right)=[\sigma \circ h]^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{s^2-s}\right),$$
where $h(\xi)= \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi}$ and $\sigma$ reduces to
$$\sigma(z)= \frac{(1+z^2-s)f'(h^{-1}(z)) + s z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}},$$
and so
$$\sigma(h(\xi))= \frac{\xi(1+f^2(\xi)/\xi^2-s)f'(\xi) + s f(\xi)}{\sqrt{\xi^2+f^2(\xi)}}.$$
Note that due to the assumption $s>1$ a solution has to fulfill $2 |f(x)f'(x)|> |x|$.
I tried a symmetric non-trivial example for $f$ and it worked. The overall 6 solutions reduced to 4.

Comment: Please do not repeatedly edit your post.  Every time you edit, you bump the post to the top of the front page, and potentially ping anyone following this post or the related tags.  Please decide what you are going to say, then say it.  One or two edits is fine, but nearly 30 is indicative of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but there exists functions which produce any value of $x$ as a solution. For example, to get $x=\chi$ as a solution, consider

$$f(x)=x-\sqrt{s^2 \chi ^2-\chi ^2}-s \chi -\chi$$

Then $f'(\chi)=1$ and after a lot of simplification we get

$$\left(f(\chi)^2+\chi^2\right) f'(\chi)^2-s \chi \left(\chi f'(\chi)^2-2 f(\chi) f'(\chi)-\chi\right)=0$$

Comment: Interesting, just for simple linear $f$. Although, $f$ takes negative values here.

Comment: Might be interesting to consider the case $f(x)=a x+b$ and then get the solution in terms of $a,b,s$.